# Is there any way to generate password protected XLSX in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, passwords, xlsx

I am looking for an npm package or any other workaround to be able to generate xlsx file with password. I do not want to protect the sheet(s) or cell(s)... I want the whole file password protected.
I found few quite good packages (excel4node, exceljs..) but none of them able to do what I need.

Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: If you are not bound to use xlsx format, I would suggest going with CSV files.
easier to read and write with json/ js native object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate) module to do this, for example:

```
const XlsxPopulate = require('xlsx-populate');

XlsxPopulate.fromBlankAsync().then(workbook => {
    workbook.sheet("Sheet1").cell("A1").value("Some sample text");
    return workbook.toFileAsync("./test.xlsx", { password: "$secret_password" });
});
```

The resulting workbook will require the user to enter the correct password if they wish to access it.

Comment: I'm using exceljs in my nest project to create a worbook in my service layer and then download it with rest api, actually I use _wb.xlsx.write(response)_  in controller, but now I need protect that file with a password. It is posible combine exceljs with xlsx-populate to do this ?

Comment: You should be able to load the xlsx file you create in exceljs into xlsx populate, then add a password.

Comment: I solved using _import * as Encryptor from 'xlsx-populate/lib/Encryptor'_ in my class (because xlsx-populate doesn't have @types), then to encrypt I used _encryptor.encrypt(await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer(), password)_, where _wb_ is Workbook created using exceljs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exceljs package, it provides a way to create write protected excel, but does not provide password protected excel sheet.

```
await worksheet.protect('the-password', options);
```

reference: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#sheet-protection

But if you want to create a password protected excel sheet then you can use xlsx-populate package.

XLSX Agile encryption and decryption are supported so you can read and write password-protected workbooks. To read a protected workbook, pass the password in as an option:

```
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./Book1.xlsx", { password: "S3cret!" })
.then(workbook => {
    // ...
});
```

Similarly, to write a password encrypted workbook:

```
workbook.toFileAsync("./out.xlsx", { password: "S3cret!" });
```

reference: https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate#encryption

Comment: This is incorrect, as ExcelJS only offers sheet protection -- not the whole workbook itself. If you use this feature, one can still open the workbook and see the contents of the Excel file; they just won't be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a generated Excel file using any npm package, then in order to add password protection to this Excel file, install xlsx-populate.
Then use the below function:

```
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(filePath).then(wb=>{
        wb.toFileAsync(filePath,{password: process.env.password})
})
```