# How do I generate password protected XLSX in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using exceljs in my angular project to create a worbook in my service layer and then download it with nodejs rest api, actually I use wb.xlsx.write(response) in controller, but now I need protect that file with a password. Is it possible to add password on the file? If so how can we achieve with exceljs npm ?

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250905/is-there-any-way-to-generate-password-protected-xlsx-in-nodejs

Comment: the lib using is exceljs and not yet have that feature, try to use some another way around, like using zip to create password, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829782/generate-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-node-js